# $(this) selector issue jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this

i have this simple jquery function here.Clicking over a button i want to alert its own class before ajax and again upon succession..but the selector **"$(this)"** in the last situation is not working and the alert returns **"undefined"**..

why?

```
$(".button").live("click",function(){

alert($(this).attr('class')); //returns "button"
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: myData,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
                alert($(this).attr('class')); //returns undefined

    }

});
```

Comment: Wow, 7 answers in 10 minutes...

Comment: yeah, all basically identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this, store `$(this)` in a variable so you can use it throughout the function without having to perform a jQuery lookup every time, and you also will not have to depend on the scope to provide the correct element for `$(this)`

```
$(".button").live("click",function(){
    var button = $(this);
    alert(button.attr('class')); //returns "button"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: myData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            alert(button.attr('class')); //should also return "button"

        }
    });
});
```

wrapping `this` only once also is a performance enhancement

Answer (score 2):

This will make it work:

```
$(".button").live("click", function() {

    var button = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: myData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert($(button).attr('class')); 
        }
    });

});
```

You cannot use the `this` reference inside nested functions. The `success` function is a nested function and it has its own `this` value. If you need the reference to the button inside that nested function, you have to declare a local variable (like `button`).

```
function clickHandler() {

    // this == element that was clicked

    function ajaxHandler() {

        // this != element that was clicked 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `var self = $(this);` when you declare the function, and then use `self` instead of `$(this)`

So your code looks like this:

```
$(".button").live("click",function(){

var self = $(this);

alert($(this).attr('class')); //returns "button"
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: myData,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
                alert(self.attr('class')); //returns undefined

    }
});
```

Comment: ill try..but wich is the explanation??

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people have posted the solution for this so I won't post the code. Just wanted to mention the reason is because since the success method is a callback your context of $(this) isn't valid anymore. So you need to assign it to a variable and store it for your own use.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` only exists when referencing an HTML object in the DOM. Since you've tried using in the success function of the AJAX call, `$(this)` has no reference. So for example, in the following code `$(this)` refers to the item to returned by the jQuery selector:

```
$('.button').each(function() {
    alert($(this));
});
```

You will need to use a selector to return the item in global scope, and then pass this to the success function in the AJAX call:

```
var myButton = $('.button');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: myData,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) { alert(myButton.attr('class')); /* returns button */ }
});
```

Comment: Actually JQuery doesn't impose any meaning to `this` through out the API, for event handlers this points to the DOM object the event was triggered from, but from other APIs it points to the 'current' element (see `$.each`) and if it's hard to guess for JQuery then it will just point to the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `context` section [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Basically, what seems to be happening in your code is that the reference to `this` no longer applies.  Makes sense, given that the context of the code has moved on while the AJAX callback is being handled asynchronously.  Explicitly setting the `context` to a particular object in the `.ajax()` call will carry a reference to the context into the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a `context: this` property to the hash that is passed to the `$.ajax` call, that way the `success` handle will it's context set properly, or you can also do something like:

```
success: $.proxy(function(html) {  // using $.proxy will bind the function scope to this
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
}, this);
```

or, another technique I've seen:

```
$(".button").live("click",function(){
    var self = this;
    alert($(self).attr('class')); //returns "button"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: myData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
                alert($(self).attr('class')); //returns undefined

        }
});
```